# Mounting a shelf into concrete, with two non-identical anchors (brackets)

Tags: drill, shelving, brackets

I have a wall shelf that I'd like to mount into a concrete wall. Unfortunately, due to a mistake I ended up with two different anchors (not sure what the term is - I think it's anchor, bracket, or chevron) - see picture below.

The shelf is going to only hold light items (less than 2kg load), and will not be easily seen. Slightly-unsightly-aspect aside, is this likely to be a (structural) problem? Should I get two identical anchors/brackets/chevrons, or is it OK to proceed with these two different ones?

[image]

Comment: Given the annoyances of drilling into concrete, and the *rather low cost* of these shelf brackets... I'd much rather use the one with 2 holes than 3, and trade/toss the 3-hole job.  Unless the strength was called for.  The lower hole is scarcely necessary in any case; its' only there to keep the bracket from turning sideways or the shelf from flipping *up*.

Comment: FWI. Terminology.  The shelf is mounted onto brackets and the brackets are mounted to the wall with anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you can decide if you can live with building a shelf with mismatched brackets like that. To me it would look like a major hack even if it was in the back of the garage or in a closet.

From a structural standpoint there should be no problem with the mismatched brackets as long as they mounted properly so that the resulting shelf surface was level and both brackets have more than enough capability to bear the load that you intend to place on the shelf.

Comment: The proper way to implement this type of shelf installation is to build a second one with the formed steel bracket on the right and the "blown shape" bracket on the left in the new location.